# Keep child element inside of it's parent (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div container(article) holding a title (m-title), description (m-description) and another div for the actual article content (m-body). The fixed div container(article) changes size depending on the article but has a max height of 80% of the viewport height.

Now, I've tried a million different things but I can't seem to keep the m-body div to stay within its parent and create a properly working scrollbar for the content.
I would have assumed setting the height of the m-body to 100% would force it to take up the remainder of the space inside it's parent, but it just goes on forever (see [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hHwg.png)). Ideally, the final product would look something like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdkCZ.png).

I've tried making a snippet example of the issue - some values might be different from the original. Keep in mind the entire article/card is supposed to be flexible in size and the title and description might vary in size making the size of m-body different every time.

```css
    article {
      height: auto;
      max-height: 512px;
      width: 512px;
      background-color: #F7F7F7;
      padding: 32px;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
      z-index: 3000;
    }

    article .m-title {
      color: #1b1b1b;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    article .m-description {
      color: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.5);
      text-transform: normal;
      font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-style: normal;
      margin-bottom: 32px;
    }

    article .m-body {
      height: 100%;
      color: #1b1b1b;
      text-transform: normal;
      font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-style: normal;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

```html
    <article id="article-3" class="hideme">
      <div onclick="contractFunction3(event)" class="close"></div>
      <h4 class="m-title">Title</h4>
      <p class="m-description">Description Description Description Description Description Description </p>
      <div class="m-body">
        <p>asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf sdf asasdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf</p>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Open the snippit in full page to see the issue.

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this property to article

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

And remove this from m-body

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

```css
article {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 512px;
  width: 512px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  padding: 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 3000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

article .m-title {
  color: #1b1b1b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

article .m-description {
  color: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.5);
  text-transform: normal;
  font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

article .m-body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  text-transform: normal;
  font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<article id="article-3" class="hideme">
  <div onclick="contractFunction3(event)" class="close"></div>
  <h4 class="m-title">Title</h4>
  <p class="m-description">Description Description Description Description Description Description </p>
  <div class="m-body">
    <p>asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf sdf asasdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf
      asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: But I only want the m-body to scroll, not all content inside the article.

Answer (score 1):

Using display: flex will fix your issue.

```
article {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's is very simple. You gave the height of m.body 100%. You have to give it px.

```css
  article {
      height: auto;
      max-height: 512px;
      width: 512px;
      background-color: #F7F7F7;
      padding: 32px;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
      z-index: 3000;
    }

    article .m-title {
      color: #1b1b1b;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    article .m-description {
      color: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.5);
      text-transform: normal;
      font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-style: normal;
      margin-bottom: 32px;
    }

    article .m-body {
      height: 200px;
      color: #1b1b1b;
      text-transform: normal;
      font-family: zeitung-micro, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-style: normal;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

```html
 <article id="article-3" class="hideme">
      <div onclick="contractFunction3(event)" class="close"></div>
      <h4 class="m-title">Title</h4>
      <p class="m-description">Description Description Description Description Description Description </p>
      <div class="m-body">
        <p>asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf sdf asasdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf</p>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Comment: But then it doesn't scale if the article div changes size.